# How work with UIScrollView and other subview touches

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, touch

I have created a UIScrollView on which various subview like UITextField,UITextView and a DropdownField (I created custom UITextField which on clicking gives a list of items in a UITableView below it).

When the user clicks on text field or DropdownField it must display the keyboard or drop down. They must disappear on clicking either return or blank space on screen for UITextField and tableview cell or blank space on screen for DropdownField

But my problem is while clicking on blank space the keyboard or dropdown is not dismissing.

When I try UITapGestureRecognizer they are dismissing but in drop down i am not able to call the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: where the selected row text is put into DropdownField.

Comment: Try setting `cancelsTouchesInView` on recognizer to NO. It should pass all other events.

Comment: @MaciejOczko i did but no use